# indexerror in python for a beginner

Tags: python, index-error

I've searched for the solution to this myself already and maybe I'm finding nothing or maybe I wouldn't even be able to recognize the correct solution.

I've completed this assignment for a course and the code works but when I put it into a code tester (required for class), I get the following message:

merge([4]) expected [4] but received (Exception: IndexError) "list index out of range" at line 16, in merge

How can I get rid of this error?
BTW this is an attempt at creating the game '2048' where non-zero numbers must go to the left and numbers that are the same will combine to produce double the value.

2 0 2 4 should become 4 4 0 0

Here is my code:

```
    def merge(line):
        """
        Function that merges a single row or column in 2048.
        """
        new_list = line
        for x in line:
            if x == 0:
                line.remove(0)
                line.append(0)
        if new_list[0] == new_list[1]:
            new_list[0] = new_list[0] * 2
            new_list.pop(1)
            new_list.append(0)
        else:
            pass
        if new_list[1] == new_list[2]:
            new_list[1] = new_list[1] * 2
            new_list.pop(2)
            new_list.append(0)
        else:
            pass
        if new_list[2] == new_list[3]:
            new_list[2] = new_list[2] * 2
            new_list.pop(3)
            new_list.append(0)
        else:
            pass
        return new_list
        return []

    #test
    print '2, 0, 2, 4 becomes', merge([2, 0, 2, 4])
```

Comment: As a side note, you can remove you `else: pass` statements.  They are redundant and not needed.  You code would be easier to read without them.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is this line of code:

```
if new_list[1] == new_list[2]:
```

I guess it's a problem due to the tester you have used. More specifically it tests your code even on wrong input, like an empty array. So you can try to insert some controls on the input, like the next:

```
if len(line) === 0: # it checks if the array is empty
```

Furthermore, over the suggestion of 16num, I suggest you delete `return []`, because this line of code is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

If the code works and you only want to handle the error that can be done by using try and except.

Here's an example where merge() is called three times, the second time it's called there is not enough numbers for the function to work, this triggers an IndexError, which is then passed so the code can keep running.

```
def merge(line):
#Function that merges a single row or column in 2048.
    try:
        new_list = line
        for x in line:
            if x == 0:
                line.remove(0)
                line.append(0)
        if new_list[0] == new_list[1]:
            new_list[0] = new_list[0] * 2
            new_list.pop(1)
            new_list.append(0)
        else:
            pass
        if new_list[1] == new_list[2]:
            new_list[1] = new_list[1] * 2
            new_list.pop(2)
            new_list.append(0)
        else:
            pass
        if new_list[2] == new_list[3]:
            new_list[2] = new_list[2] * 2
            new_list.pop(3)
            new_list.append(0)
        else:
            pass
        return new_list
        return []
    except IndexError:
        #print('index error')
        pass


#test
print('2, 0, 2, 4 becomes', merge([2, 0, 2, 4]))
print('2, 0, 2 triggers an index error, which is passed and the code keeps running', merge([2, 0, 2]))
print('2, 0, 2, 4 becomes', merge([2, 0, 2, 4]))
```